# integration of differential equation for wind profile

Tags: integration

I'm trying to calculate the vertical wind speed gradient with some equations and am having trouble with the integration. From the book I'm using, the wind profile is calculated according to
$$\frac{kz}{u_*}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\phi_m(\zeta),$$

where k is the von karman constant, z is height, u* is the air friction velocity, du/dz is the change in wind speed with change in height i.e. the wind profile, and psi_m(zeta) is an atmospheric stability function where
$$\zeta=\frac{z}{L}$$

and L is the Monin obukhov length scale which is just an expression of atmospheric stability. The book states that psi_m(zeta) can be integrated between z1 and z2 i.e. two different heights to obtain the wind gradient as
$$u_2-u_1=\frac{u_*}{k}\left[\ln\left(\frac{z_2}{z_1}\right)-\psi_m\left(\frac{z_2}{L}\right)+\psi_m\left(\frac{z_1}{L}\right)\right]$$

where 
$$\psi_m(\zeta)=\int_{z_0/L}^{\zeta}\frac{[1-\psi_m(x)]}{x}\text{d}x$$

Im finding it really hard to make the link between these equations and coming up with a step by step solution to the wind profile. Could anyone explain what the author has done and how the step by step process should look like? I havent posted this on the physics stack exchange seeing as it is a problem with the mathematical procedure I am having and not in understanding the process.

Comment: It's a little hard for me to parse the left hand side of your first equation.  What is being differentiated?  Or is it a vector field, in which case what is $\phi_m$?  By the way, do you mean $\psi_m$ there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for the wind profile should be

$$\frac{kz}{u_*}\frac{\partial \bar{U}}{\partial z}=\phi_m(\zeta),$$

where $\bar{U}$ is the mean wind-speed profile. The trick will be writing $\phi_m=1-(1-\phi_m)$. Thus, dividing by $z$ and integrating gives:

$$\frac{k}{u_*}\left.\bar{U}\right|_{z_1}^{z_2}=\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{\phi_m(\zeta)}{z}dz=\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{1-(1-\phi_m(\zeta))}{z}dz=\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{dz}{z}-\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{(1-\phi_m(\zeta))}{z}dz$$

so upon substituting $z=x L$, to give:

$$\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{(1-\phi_m(z/L))}{z}dz=\int_{z_1/L}^{z_2/L}\frac{1-\phi_m(x)}{xL}Ldx=\psi_m(z_2/L)-\psi_m(z_1/L)$$

where you now use the *correct* definition of the **momentum influence function**:

$$\psi_m(\zeta):=\int_{z_{0,m}/L}^\zeta\frac{1-\phi_m(x)}{x}dx$$

where $z_{0,m}$ is some base value. Then

$$\frac{k}{u_*}(u_2-u_1)=\ln\left(\frac{z_2}{z_1}\right)-\psi_m\left(\frac{z_2}{L}\right)+\psi_m\left(\frac{z_1}{L}\right).$$

As an aside, the point of writing $\psi_m$ is to quantify the difference of the windprofile when you are in the stable vs unstable regime. For example, if $\phi_m(x)=1$, then you are in the perfectly stable regime, $\psi_m=0$ so you get back the usual log-wind profile law.

Comment: I'm still not getting all of this I'm afraid. Firstly, should the first few integrals be from z1 to z2 not z1 to z? Secondly, I can't see where ln(z2/z1) comes from at this stage? Thirdly, prior to substituting PSI_m(zeta) into the final equation how does the integral change from being int_{z1}^{z2} to int_{z1/L}^{z}?

Comment: @Kate: I've corrected a few offending typos involving $z_2$. Also some extra details have been added. I'm beginning to think your book has a typo. Let me know if this doesn't work out.

Comment: Ah yes, the book does state PSI(zeta) as you have shown above, does this alter the equations much?

Comment: Also, if z = xL, where does the 1/L come from? and shouldnt the denominator be xL not x/L

Comment: @Kate: I think I wanted to write $x/L$ to keep it unitless. I've reformulated it as you said (both give the same result). As far as $\psi$ goes, I'm pretty sure the definition I gave is canon. I'm bewildered where the second $\psi$ term comes from if the integral is indeed from $z_1/L$ and not some $z_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasnt clear in my response above, you are right it is z0 not z1/L.

Comment: @Kate: Ah. Then you get your book's answer, with the extra $\psi$ term as you first postulated in your question.

Comment: When you say substitute z = xL, why isn't this included in the dz/z integral?

Comment: $dz=Ldx$ as it appears above, no?

Comment: above you have written $\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{dz}{z}-\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{(1-\phi_m(\zeta))}{z}dz$ and then stated that you substitute z = xL, but you only seem to substitute it for the second half of the equation i.e. not in $\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{dz}{z}$ ?

Comment: The substitution is only necessary for the second integral to put it in the form of the momentum influence function. You could do it for the first integral as well but the answer would be the same